# Ramer–Douglas–Peucker algorithm (RDP) Python implementation: How to Plot it and use it with dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm, matplotlib

I simply want to use the Ramer–Douglas–Peucker algorithm (RDP) and its Python implementation to reduce jitternez from pricecharts.

So i tried the following:

```
import yfinance as yf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from rdp import rdp


stock = 'AMZN'
start = '2020-11-01'

df = yf.download(stock , start=start)



nfx = []
nfy = []

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    
    x_data = nfx.append(index)
    y_data = nfy.append(row['Close'])
rdpp = [rdp(np.array([nfy]), epsilon=0.2)]


plt.plot(rdpp)
plt.show()
```

this however does not work.
Either i get error messages or an empty plot.

What can i do/improve to make that work?

Here is the Documentation, but its small and i dont really get how to apply this in my case. --> https://pypi.org/project/rdp/

Thanks a lot, best wishes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `rdp` function wants a **N by 2 array** as input, where N is the number of points and 2 is the dimension (it could be 3D too).

One way to build this 2D array is using [numpy's column_stack](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html) function. Also, the `index` has to be converted to a numeric value, for instance to a number of seconds.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import yfinance as yf
from rdp import rdp

stock = "AMZN"
start = "2020-11-01"

dataframe = yf.download(stock, start=start)

nfx, nfy = [], []
for index, row in dataframe.iterrows():
    nfx.append(index.timestamp())
    nfy.append(row["Close"])

# print(nfx)
points = np.column_stack([nfx, nfy])
print("points.shape:", points.shape)
points_after_rdp = rdp(points, epsilon=80)

# Graph
plt.plot(points_after_rdp[:, 0], points_after_rdp[:, 1], color="red", label="after RDP")
plt.plot(
    points[:, 0], points[:, 1], color="black", label="before", alpha=0.7, linewidth=1
)
plt.xlabel("time (s)")
plt.ylabel("Close")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

The graph look like this:
[image: resulting_graph]