# Ramer Douglas Peucker algorithm applied to list of coordinates: Strings to floats

Tags: python, string, floating-point

I have a list of 466 lat/lon-coordinate pairs as follows:

```
pos = ['52,13','53,15',....,'54,16']
```

I would like to apply the RDP algorithm in order to reduce this list to just 8 coordinates.

I am using the following code:

```
length = len(pos)/2
length = int(length)

b = rdp(a.reshape(length, 2))
print (b)
```

This yields the following error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
```

How to resolve the issue that the items in the array are strings ?

Comment: Perhaps [Ramer–Douglas–Peucker algorithm (RDP) Python implementation: How to Plot it and use it with dataframes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69500354/2410359) is useful?

Comment: hi, thanks for the comment. I see the logic being used there, however, what would I use as the dataframe variable in my example? Since pos is not a dataframe in my code but just a list?